# How can I pass a connection object to a closure

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code to escape posted data:

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    $trimmed_post = array_map('trim', $_POST);

    $bk = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $trimmed_post['bk_id']);
    $ad = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $trimmed_post['address']);
    $ti = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $trimmed_post['bkTitle']);
    $ta = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $trimmed_post['tags']);
    $de = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $trimmed_post['description']);
```

but I would prefer to do this - it's neater:

```
list($bk, $ad, $ti, $ta, $de) = array_map(function ($x) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $x);
}, $trimmed_post);
```

I'm using MySql 5.5.16, but it returns "Undefined variable: dbc".

I suspect it is a 'closure' issue. How can I pass $dbc into my lambda pl?

Comment: You're better off using [prepared statements](http://php.net/PDO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `use` keyword.

```
list($bk, $ad, $ti, $ta, $de) = array_map(function ($x) use ($dbc) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $x);
}, $trimmed_post);
```

But honestly, you should be using **[Prepared Statements](http://il.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)**.

Comment: I did not know about 'use', thank you. I appreciate the comments about prepared statements, although I do not see how it is pertinent to my question. In particular "Using a prepared statement is not always the most efficient way of executing a statement. A prepared statement executed only once causes more client-server round-trips than a non-prepared statement. This is why the SELECT is not run as a prepared statement above."

Comment: Ahh.. I see that a prepared statement will escape the characters for me. But given that I'm running a query once-only I'm happy with my current approach (see the quote in my previous comment). Andy.

Comment: Prepared statements is also a security measure to avert SQL injections. Further if you are using prepared statements your code would be much simpler than it is now as it devoid the escape logic.